# is it safe to quit a loop with a return statement while iterating over a vector?

Tags: c++, loops, iterator, exit

I'm not at ease with the way memory's managed in the following example :

```
void X::foo(void) {

  // test1 :
  for (auto i = this->vec.begin(); i != this->vec.end(); ++i) {
        if ( ... ) {
            return;
        }
    }

  // test2
  ...

  // test3
  ...
}
```

Even if there's no memory allocation for iterators, I would like to be sure that there's no problem quitting such abruptly the loop. Is it safer to *break* the loop, check the result of the test and then quit the function without passing throuh test2 and test3 ?

Comment: Think a little more about it: from the loop's "point of view", is there really a difference in workflow between `break` and `return`?

Comment: are you concerned the iterators aren't deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is safe as long as you return any possibly allocated resources back to the system. If you are in c++ and utilizing structures who properly implement the ideas of [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), e.g., `shared_ptr` etc. Then there will be no problem.

Return essentially "immediately" leaves the function call. However, before it does, the compiler ensures destruction of any temporary objects first.

Comment: This + I would add: make sure your code is readable. If it contains too many points of return, readability is worse, but on the other hand, return can simplify a lots of things. In certain company I was forced to keep "single return point" and now I stick with it even thought it makes coding little more difficult sometimes. But not much...

Answer (score 1):

variables declared inside the for are allocated in the "automatic memory" meaning that they will exist inside the variables scope itself: "i" will be deallocated automatically when it goes out of scope.

so yes, it's safe to return "abruptly" from the loop.